# IOS/Objective-C: retrieving ManagedObjectID within loop error

Tags: ios, loops, core-data

I am having trouble setting and retrieving a `managedObjectId` within a loop.  First problem, I can't find in the docs what the parts of the MOID mean.  So first question, are the following moids unique? The only way that they are different is in the last digit after the entity name, Item. If not, that could be the issue.

```
0xd000000054200000 <x-coredata://10EC1628-A6D4-487B-BF5C-61EAD9838132/Item/p5384>
0xd000000054240000 <x-coredata://10EC1628-A6D4-487B-BF5C-61EAD9838132/Item/p5385>
```

Second question, if they unique, when I retrieve the record associated with these ids, I end up retrieving the same record. So maybe there is a problem in the loop below.

Here is my code simplified slightly as there is a sync to server that I have not included.

```
//NSArray * myItems is an array of items to be saved
 for (i=0;i<max;i++)
 { 
     currentItem = myItems[i];
     // Create Entity
     NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Item" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];      
    // Initialize Record
        NSManagedObject *record = [[NSManagedObject alloc] initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];     
        // Populate Record
        [record setValue:currentName forKey:@"name"];          
          // Save Record
        NSError *error = nil;      
        if ([self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {       
            //Set moID in ivar of saved record
           self.moID = [record objectID];  
[self syncAndMarkSynced];   
}
}//close loop

-(void) syncAndMarkSynced{
//sync to server omitted
 Items *object = [self.managedObjectContext objectRegisteredForID:self.moID];
object.synced = @1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> First problem, I can't find in the docs what the parts of the MOID mean.

That's because they are not documented. The object ID is unique; the details are not explained because the parts of the URI are not intended to be meaningful on their own.

> Second question, if they unique, when I retrieve the record associated with these ids, I end up retrieving the same record.

That's expected. A managed object has a unique ID. When you look up a managed object by ID, you're requesting the same entry from the persistent store. Each entry has a unique ID, so if you use the ID, you get that entry.

> So maybe there is a problem in the loop below.

It's not clear to me what the loop is trying to do. Hopefully the information above will help you work it out.

Comment: Are the two ids shown above the same or are they different?  I would have thought if different they would have a very different set of characters, but they differ only in the last digit.  Second, unless, I am misunderstanding something, I would think that a unique MO id would return a unique MO.  Instead, giving it two different MOIDs--if the two ids above are different--I get only one (identical) MO.  I guess I should double check, a managed object is the same as a record, correct?

Comment: "Record" is not a term used in Core Data, but in general a single managed object corresponds to a single SQLite record. Any chance you just have two managed objects with identical fields? That's what your symptoms seem to indicate.

Comment: No.  absolutely different MOs.  They display as two different items with different names etc. in tableview and detail view.  Can you clarfiy that the two objectids above are in fact different: <x-coredata://10EC1628-A6D4-487B-BF5C-61EAD9838132/Item/p5384> vs. <x-coredata://10EC1628-A6D4-487B-BF5C-61EAD9838132/Item/p5385>. Note they differ only in p5384 vs. p5385